# Can p-value tells which variable is the major factor to the outcome?

Tags: p-value, chi-squared

I have trouble dealing with one of the task in this [data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/whenamancodes/students-performance-in-exams?datasetId=2478649) from kaggle: to find the major factor in test outcomes, the factors are all categorical.

Can p-value in `stats.chi2_contingency()` tells which variable has the greatest impact on each test outcomes?(lower p-value indicates that there is stronger relationship between two variables, factor and test outcome)

Is it the right method to use? Thanks!!

[image]

```
sub = ['math', 'reading', 'writing']
factors = list(df.columns[:5])

for x in sub:
    for y in factors:
        subject = np.where(df[f'{x} score']>=60, 1, 0) #score above 60 means good. 
        obseved = pd.crosstab(index = df[f'{y}'], columns=subject)
        p_value = stats.chi2_contingency(observed=obseved)[1]
        print(f'Subject: {x}, Factor: {y}, P-value: {p_value}')
    print('===========')



result:

Subject: math, Factor: gender, P-value: 4.327453315859715e-07
Subject: math, Factor: race/ethnicity, P-value: 8.606440583769172e-09
Subject: math, Factor: parental level of education, P-value: 1.3038966941106568e-06
Subject: math, Factor: lunch, P-value: 7.991906038402147e-23
Subject: math, Factor: test preparation course, P-value: 0.03659940205943433
===========
Subject: reading, Factor: gender, P-value: 0.00021136247670793947
Subject: reading, Factor: race/ethnicity, P-value: 0.0013115634444564267
Subject: reading, Factor: parental level of education, P-value: 0.00040600676669462395
Subject: reading, Factor: lunch, P-value: 8.774296142015978e-11
Subject: reading, Factor: test preparation course, P-value: 3.060148315231233e-10
===========
Subject: writing, Factor: gender, P-value: 6.85909966324548e-08
Subject: writing, Factor: race/ethnicity, P-value: 0.00117283769110293
Subject: writing, Factor: parental level of education, P-value: 8.278387435600882e-05
Subject: writing, Factor: lunch, P-value: 1.5790148042752678e-16
Subject: writing, Factor: test preparation course, P-value: 4.553365478101716e-15
===========
```

right way to test which variable has the most impact on outcome.

Comment: Well, that table seems to show a very clear leader for each subject.

Comment: but how to know which variables(race, gender, etc) have more impact on each subject(math score, reading score and writing score)?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  Each subject has one obvious maximum.  Prep for math, race for reading and writing, although the connection is less than for math.